# What could be causing this PHP - MySQL bind error?

Tags: php

> You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual  that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near '?,?' at line
>   1

I never had an issue with the code before so I am guessing it must have something to do with the MySQL version (MySQL 4.1.25 & PHP 5).

Here is the code I am using:

```
  $sql = "a long sql select statement... ?,?";

  if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)) 
    {
        // it never even gets here
        $stmt->bind_param('ii',$offset,$limit);
        ... 
    }
  else
    {   
        echo($mysqli->error);
    }
```

Comment: You can't bind to the values of LIMIT in a prepared statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot bind x and y in `LIMIT x,y` because only data can be bound.

As an alternative, you can add $offset and $limit directly in your code (after validating) and use the following without binding $offset and $limit:

```
$sql = "a long sql select statement... $offset,$limit";
```

Comment: Could you expand on why this is? I had no issue with it on another server. I am using "ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT ?,?". How can I fix it?

Comment: @Mike, you can only use bind data, and the numbers for LIMIT does not count as data.

Comment: Mike, just write LIMIT $x, $y right into your query. You'll have to validate $x and $y yourself if they are user input.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. I ended up just hard coding the limit.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the accepted answer is correct.  I just tried with MySQL5.0.7 and PHP 5.3.3. and it works without problems.

Was there recently an update from PHP <5.3 to 5.3+ on this server?

If yes, this may cause the problems(it's not clear, how you pass the parameters):
PHP 5.3+ requires to pass the parameters of  bind_param() by reference, in earlier versions this wasn't required.