# Attach data in array in a php mysqli prepared statement

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am tyring to write a simple function here. The idea is to be able to call the function and display the data, but i am wondering if there is a way to stuff it into an array of some sort or something so that i can style the results when the function is called. the function is as follows:

```
function getDBH() {
    static $DBH = null;
    if (is_null($DBH)) {
        $DBH = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
    }
    return $DBH;
}
function selectInfo($limit, $offset){
    $DBH = getDBH();
    $stmt = $DBH->prepare("SELECT * FROM information LIMIT ?,?");
    $stmt->bind_param("ii", $limit, $offset);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($id, $name, $email);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What could be causing this PHP - MySQL bind error ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4247913/what-could-be-causing-this-php-mysql-bind-error) ... you cannot bind limit and offset

Comment: I don't understand your request. You have a function that connects to a database, and one that executes a prepared statement. Where do you want to do something involving some array?

Comment: If it's just `LIMIT` you're setting here, there's not really any point to use a prepared statement.  Just a traditional `query()` would be fine as long as you cast and/or validate each value as an int.

Comment: @ajreal: you can bind to `LIMIT` in mysql 5.0.7+.  see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html

Comment: @Dan Grossman, Yeah, The function creates a connection to the database, queries the database, and I am trying to stick the data it retrieves into an array that i can pull from when i call the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This replacement for your `selectInfo()` function should return a multi-dimensional array containing one associative array per record.  It does not rely on you knowing before hand what fields are returned in the statement as that `*` in the select statement can otherwise easily break things if you alter your table in any way.

```
function selectInfo($limit, $offset) {
    $DBH = getDBH();
    $limit = (int) $limit;
    $offset= (int) $offset;
    $stmt = $DBH->prepare("SELECT * FROM information LIMIT ?,?");
    $stmt->bind_param("ii", $limit, $offset);
    $stmt->execute();
    // get all field info in returned set
    $result_metadata = $stmt->result_metadata();
    $result_fields = $result_metadata->fetch_fields();  
    $result_metadata->free_result();
    unset($result_metadata);
    $bind_array = array();
    $current_row = array();
    $all_rows = array();
    foreach($result_fields as $val) {
        // use returned field names to populate associative array
        $bind_array[$val->name] = &$current_row[$val->name];
        }
    // bind results to associative array
    call_user_func_array(array($stmt, "bind_result"), $bind_array);
    // continually fetch all records into associative array and add it to final $all_rows array
    while($stmt->fetch()) $all_rows[] = $current_row;
    return $all_rows;
    }
```

**Edit:** Changed up your `selectInfo()` function a bit as my previous answer was just too sloppy.  `print_r(selectInfo(0,10));` will print out all records with field names intact.

Comment: Thanks, im pretty sure that is exactly what i am looking for, although i am new to this mysqli prepared statement thing. How would i end up echoing the results? after i call the function?

Comment: @mcbeav: not sure I understand.  `$records = selectInfo(5, 10); echo $records[3]["name"];` should give you the name of the name of the person in the 4th record pulled.  It's up to you how to put that on your web page.

Comment: thanks bob-the-destroyer for the excellent answer. I appreciate all of the help here.

Comment: @mcbeav: no problem.  I actually completely changed my answer to replace your `selectInfo()` function.  So it should be more clear now.

Comment: This didn't work for me, $all_rows array ended having the same array many times, so I assigned the $current_rows to a temporary array, replaced `while($stmt->fetch()) $all_rows[] = $current_row;` WITH `while($stmt->fetch()) { foreach ($current_row as $k => $v) { $tmp[$k] = $v; } $all_rows[] = $tmp; }`

Answer (score 3):

```
$stmt->bind_result($id, $name, $email);

while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
    $row = array('id' => $id, 'name' => $name, 'email' => $email);
    $rows[] = $row;
}

return $rows;
```

Comment: Thanks Dan for the excellent answer. I have a quick question fi you could help me here. I don't know much here, so i apoligize in advance, but shouldn't I now be able to call the function and be able to print it like :   print $id[1]; print $id[2];

Comment: +1 for making me notice I was doing it wrong in one of my own personal projects.  For some reason, I thought it necessary to call `bind_result` inside the while loop.

Comment: @mcbeav: You'll have an array of arrays. Each entry in the outer array is a row. Each row has keys id, name and email. If you want the name from the first row returned by the function, `echo $rows[0]['name']`.

Answer (score 1):

Use ! instead of ? to attach static data. ? attaches quoted, escaped data.  ! is unsafe, but not for limit.

Comment: yeah, i could, this is basically just for the sake of me learning a little here. I learned PHP, but nothing about prepared statements, so this sort of thing is completley new to me, and to be honest a bit confusing.